# AppManifest.xml vs WMAppManifest.xml - class libraries in Windows Phone 7 apps

Tags: windows-phone-7, manifest

Before I submit my first app to the Windows Phone 7 Marketplace, I would like to know whether I should modify the AppManifest.xml file.

My app comprises of two assemblies (the app + class library) and I was wondering if I have to use Deployment.Parts in the AppManifest in order to pass the certification process.

Anybody has any experience with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Windows Phone 7 Application Certification Requirements](http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/B/A/ABA09BC7-8338-4C04-9DA9-1224CD575636/Windows%20Phone%207%20Application%20Certification%20Requirements.pdf):

> 4.1.1 List of Package Requirements
>
> The XAP package must contain the
>   following
>
> a. A valid Windows Phone application
>   manifest file, named
>   WMAppManifest.xml.
>
> b. The  element in the
>   WMAppManifest.xml file must contain
>   the application title. The 
>   element must not be empty. The
>   Application title entered in Step 2 of
>   the submission process to Windows
>   Phone Marketplace and the title
>   displayed on the phone must be the
>   same.
>
> c. A valid .NET application manifest
>   file, named AppManifest.xml.
>
> d. The assembly files as specified in
>   the AppManifest.xml file.

So the answer would be yes - you need to declare the used assemblies in AppManifest.xml before submitting the application to the Marketplace.

These are referenced in AppManifest.xaml automatically when the XAP package is built. When working in Visual Studio, though, the file will remain empty.

Comment: Considering the answer by Technium - shouldn't Visual Studio put the app's dll and all referenced class libraries in this AppManifest file?

Comment: When you are in Visual Studio, AppManifest.xml will be empty. When the XAP package is built, all additionally referenced assemblies will be listed as deployment parts in AppManifest.

Answer (score 0):

Unless something is going wrong then Visual Studio should do all the work for you and you should not need to modify this file at all.