# what is the difference between AppManifest.xml and WMAppManifest.xml

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7

I am learning how to create a windows mobile app.  I've learned that 
WMAppManifest.xml contains information about the app and such..

Under the project properties folder there are three files one is AssemblyInfo.cs, AppManifest.xml and WMAppManifest.xml

What is the difference between the AppManifest.xml and WMAppManifest.xml ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AppManifest.xml vs WMAppManifest.xml - class libraries in Windows Phone 7 apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114025/appmanifest-xml-vs-wmappmanifest-xml-class-libraries-in-windows-phone-7-apps)

Comment: @Will I saw that question earlier.. but it doesn't really explain the difference between the two types of files..

Comment: Yeah, it tells you what each is.  The docs on msdn tell you what they are for.  Have you read the docs?